# Select value in dropdown and remove selected value in cloned dropdown boxes

Tags: jquery

I have a dropdown select with some values, and a button that clones that dropdown so I can add multiple dropdowns to set values in them.Values selected in the cloned dropdowns shouldn't be available in other dropdowns, and if I change the selected value(in case user changes his mind) it should update the other dropdowns.How can I accomplish this with jquery?

```
    <select class="firstCallDropDown" name="contactTypes">
<option value="1">Home</option>
<option value="2">e-mail</option>
<option value="3">Mobile</option>
<option value="4">Mobile2</option>
<option value="5">Work</option>
</select>

<a href ="#" id=addContactNumber>Add</a>
```

the jquery:

```
$("#calls_column").delegate("#addContactNumber", "click", function(event) {
            var firstDrop = $(".firstCallDropDown:first");
            var clonedDrop = firstDrop.clone();
            clonedDrop.find("option:selected").removeAttr("selected");
            clonedSip.appendTo("#numbers");
            refreshDropdowns();

        });

function refreshDropdowns(){
   var values = $("select[name='contactTypes']");

            $(values).each(function () {
                var text = $(this).children('option:selected').val();
                var options = $("option[value='" + text + "']:not(:selected)");

                $(options).each(function () {
                    $(this).remove();
                });
            });
}
```

this is what I have so far!

Comment: is it not equal to multiple select ina  same dropdown ?

Comment: I think not because I clone the dropdown and the cloned ones must not have the selected values like the other ones.(selected values must be hidden)I used remove but I think it's not good because it removes it completely...